# Distribution of n binomial trials with probability 1/i as n goes to infinity

Tags: probability, limits

Consider flipping $n$ independent coins -- the $i$-th coin flipped has probability of $\frac{1}{i}$ of being heads, and tails otherwise (in particular, the first coin is always heads). For example, with $3$ coins, the first coin is 100% heads, the second is 50% heads, and the third is $\frac{100}{3}$% heads.

As $n$ goes to infinity, can you proof or disproof that for any given positive integer constant $k$, the probability that there will be at least $k$ heads is $1$?

Comment: Im pretty sure that when you have situation that a success become less rare as you $n$ gets larger, then binomial converges to poisson distribution

Comment: Does that still applies if the product $np$ is not fixed? In this case, $np$ goes to infinity as well (since $np$ is basically the $n$-th harmonic number).

Comment: yea the more and more I think about this, poisson approximation doesn't sound like its going to work

Comment: Borel-Cantelli lemma (with independence) gives everything one wants here (and yes, the number of heads converges to infinity, almost surely).

Comment: Awesome! If you answer something like "Use the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma" I will accept the answer.

Comment: @user159813 That approach would apply if, as Irvin suggests, $np$ is fixed, so that $p = 1/\lambda n$ for some $lambda > 0$. In that case, the limit approaches $1 - e^{-1/\lambda}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borel-Cantelli lemma (with independence) shows that the number of heads converges to infinity, almost surely, because the sum of probabilities of heads $\sum\limits_i1/i$ diverges. Thus, for every $k$, the probability that there are at least $k$ heads before time $n$ goes to $1$ when $n\to\infty$.